# Building a basic custom search engine in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating a small finical analysis spreadsheet in Google Sheets. I would like to be able to type in a stock ticker, and have whatever ticker in that cell, be inserted into a URL, which will then search for that ticker. I have no issue using the `=IMPORTHTML` function, however it is currently being used like this:

`=IMPORTHTML("https://money.cnn.com/quote/financials/financials.html?symb= INSERT SYMBOL HERE &dataSet=CFS", "table")`

Where I have written "insert symbol here" is where any ticker can go to be searched, but I do not know how to make it search for whatever is in a specific cell. For example, if I type my ticker in A1, how can I make it search for whatever is written in there.

I have unsuccessfully tried something that looks like:

`"https://money.cnn.com/quote/financials/financials.html?symb="A1"&dataSet=CFS"`

Comment: Welcome! You missed the concatenation character( ampersand, **&**) - surround **A1** on both sides like as **"&A1&"** : `=IMPORTHTML("https://money.cnn.com/quote/financials/financials.html?symb="&A1&"&dataSet=CFS", "table")`

Comment: Related#1: [Can you change the importhtml address for the website URL automatically?...](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/149640/196152). Related#2: [How to reference a Cell in a =IMPORTHTML string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61118389/1330560)